# Real random variable and independent observations

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a real random variable and $X_1,\ldots ,X_p$ be $p$ independent observations of $X$. Let $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ be a simple random sample. We define, for every $x\in\mathbb R$
$$
P_X(x) = \mathbb P(x\in[\min\{X_1,\ldots ,X_p\},\max\{X_1,\ldots ,X_p\}])
$$
and
$$
P_{X,n}(x) = \binom{n}{p}^{-1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_p\leq n}\text{I}_{\{x\in[\min\{x_{i_1},\ldots ,x_{i_p}\},\max\{x_{i_1},\ldots ,x_{i_p}\}]\}}
$$

I want to show that

$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|P_X(x) - P_{X,n}(x)|\longrightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty} 0, \text{ a.s.} [\mathbb P]
$$

My idea is to express $P_X(x)$ in terms of the distribution function and apply the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, but I am not sure if it works with no restriction in the distribution (some continuity hypothesis).

Thanks in advance.